# Trying to figure out arrays as function parameters

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I've just started learning about arrays as function parameters and I just cant seem to wrap my head around it. I'm trying to create a function that asks a user to enter the values of the matrix and then reads the matrix back to them. However I can't seem to get it to work, below is an example of one of my attempts. Can anyone help me figure out how to get it to work? Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void fillinvalues(int m[4]){
cout<<"Enter the first element in your matrix\n";
cin>>m[0];
cout<<"Enter the second element in your matrix \n";
cin>>m[1];
cout<<"Enter the third element in your matrix \n";
cin>>m[2];
cout<<"Enter the fourth element in your matrix \n";
cin>> m[3];
cout<<m[0]<<","<<m[1]<<"\n"<<m[2]<<","<<m[3];


}

int main(){

fillinvalues();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "m" array isn't magically created, you need to pass one to the function

Comment: fillinvalues needs an input of integer array whose size is 4. unfortunately, u provided nothing when calling the function in main!

Comment: @Decipher But note that it will accept any pointer to `int`.

Comment: I suppose array decaying is step II, now for step I -> "you need to supply an argument to the function"

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the parameter of `fillinvalues()`,

```
    int main(){

       int m[4];
       fillinvalues(m);

       return 0;
    }
```

Btw, for the definition of `fillinvalues`, you don't need to supply the number 4.

So you can use

```
    void fillinvalues(int m[]) {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: In this case `int m[4]` is better than `int m[]`. Function is not safe anyway but at least former shows to observer the intention to work with array of size 4.

Comment: @kotlomoy I'd say the best is `int* m`, that way there is no confusion. Otherwise inexperienced users might assume they get a compiler error if they don't pass a size-4 array.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'd say `int (* m)[4]` is better.

Comment: @kotlomoy I would prefer passing the array by reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oh, I forgot that this is c++ question :) Then I would prefer not using array at all :)